PHP-FPM access to /home Folder
I'm having an issue with a PHP script not being able to access the /home folder. This is only an issue from the browser, cli has no issue. The error being returned is "Failed to open directory: Permission denied"  I have read that there is a systemd setting ProtectHome that if set to false should allow a user with the correct permissions to access the /home folder. There is no issues accessing other folders.
This appears to be a permissions issue as I'm not getting a "Directory no found" error. Just don't know what else to try.
I have set this in both the php82-php-fpm.service and httpd.service, in addtion to trying different folder permissions and changing the user/group to apache/apache.
I have resized the /home to a smaller size and created two Logical Volumes with mounts /home and /alldata to see if I'm able to access /alldata. Same issue for both mounts, error is "Failed to open directory: Permission denied in". So the web process can see the folder just not open and it is not just a /home issue as I originally thought.
Here some additional information.

OS is AlmaLinux 9.4
web server (apache) user is apache/apache
php-fpm.d/www.conf user is apache/apache
logical drive is mounted as /home
/home owner is root/root 0755
/home/buser owner is buser/buser 0755
/home/buser/backup owner is apache/apache 0755 (folder trying to read)
I tried 0777 on all the folders as well. Same issues
I have also tried setting the user to apache/apache starting at the /home folder
the web process can access any folder off the Logical Volume mounted as /root
the php script run from command line can open/access /home and /alldata


Does the folder you're trying to access have world read permissions? Permissions should be drwxr-xr-x.

You need to keep in mind that requests from a browser are handled by a server side process, the http server. That process has a different user account on the server side system compared to your personal account you are using with PHP on CLI. So it might very well be that you have different permissions in those cases. 1. find out what user account the http server process is executed under (typically something likem "www-run" or similar), then check if that use account has access to your home folder (usually not) and what you have to change to your folders permissions for that.

Thanks, I have tried both different permissions as well as setting the user and group to that used by the web server (apache). Does not seem to make any difference

One other thing I have tried is creating a mount bind to the folder.

Please revise your question and add this new information to the question itself. Document in detail what user and group account your http server process is excuted under along with the exact file system permissions of that home folder and all folders below leading up to it.

add a symlink to your target and make sure the option "FollowSymLinks" is enabled. It should work if you have proper rights on that folder, such as 0755. Remember the user accessing it is possibly 'apache'.
